# jQueryUI tabs with function in "show" option always show default effect

Tags: jquery-ui

When I include a function in "show" option in jQueryUI 1.9.1 tabs widget, default effect (fadeIn) always activates. Is there a way to have a function called on show, but without the effect?

```
$("#divTabContainer").tabs({
    "show": function(){
        var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(false);
        if ( table.length > 0 ) {
            console.log(table);
            $(table).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
        }
    }
});
```

I've tried to return false or null from the function, but it didn't have any influence, the effect was still there. In jQUI 1.8.1 this didn't happen, i.e. the function was called without the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQueryUI [`tabs/#option-show`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-show) is a method to control how the tab is shown. If you want to add a function when a tab is activated, or just before it is activated then the in-built callback methods `activate` or [`beforeActivate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate) should be used.

For example:

```
$('#divTabContainer').tabs({
  show: false, /* turn off the effect */
  beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
    // your function to adjust the dataTables column sizing
  }
});
```

Comment: `beforeActivate` didn't work (I assume because the tab was still hidden when datatables tried to resize the columns), but `activate` did the trick, even without using `show:false`. Thank you.

Comment: Ah ok, I've used datatables before and it can be fiddly to get the columns resizing nicely on a refresh. Good to hear the `activate` method worked. Looks like the default for _show_ is `null`, which I guess means no animation :-)